# How To install [lshw] command on XenServer 5.5?

Tags: linux, yum, rpm, xen

I have to collect hardware information from my hardware, especially the Hard Disk. So I need to use the Linux command-line `lshw` in order to have what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure XenServer uses rpm. You can grab `lshw` [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/9252710/com/lshw-B.02.13-3.fc9.i386.rpm.html) (32-bit) or [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/9253826/com/lshw-B.02.13-3.fc9.x86_64.rpm.html) (64-bit).